# Pass and Receive data using API CUrl using php

Tags: php, forms, curl

I have 3 forms which should work with one another. 
1. Form 1 (main) = Input Page (I want to input here my name and age)
2. Form 2 (curl) =  Curl Page (Whenever I run this page it echos the  whole form 1 instead of getting the data in form 1)
3. Form 3 (Processing) = test Page (Curl will forward grabbed data from Input Page)

*Take note that I only need the data and not the form itself as the from 2 just replicates form 1. Don't know where I got it wrong but stuck here for house.

**Form 1(main)**

```
<html>
 <body>

  <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
     Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
     <input type = "submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
<?php
  if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] ) {

  echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
  echo "You are ". $_POST['age']. " years old.";

  exit();
}
?>
```

**Form2(Curl)**

```
    <?php
  //set POST variables
  $url = 'http://localhost:81/altap/main.php';
  $data = array(
    'fname' => urlencode($_POST["name"]),
    'lname' => 'TestL',
    'test' => array(
        'first' => 'TestFirst',
        'second' => 'TestSecond'
    )
   );
  //print_r($data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($url);

$json_data = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
/* curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))
);

// execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

When I run main then run curl.php, curl.php will just replicate the form of main.php.

Can someone help me with this please. Thanks in advance for the help.

In Addition to this, how can I pass all data gathered by curl.php from main.php to test.php and how will i receive the data from curl.php using test.php

Comment: why do you want to use curl ?

Comment: The Main page will be given to my sister. Then the curl page will be on my server as well as the test page. I'm using curl so as not to expose the code if in case http posting is to be used. I want the mainpage to be the only page that they will see.